magento 2.4.4 locale parameter not working with paypal pay later button
I'm trying  to integrate paypal pay later button in my magento website. I don't use paypal through braintree but  instead I use the original magento-paypal module. The module itself works, and when I enable the solution via backend, I can see the pay later button on my checkout in frontend.
My problem is that the locale options don't work. Let me explain:
On paypal website, the official sdk documentation states that you can force the buttons' language by using the "locale" parameter. If I do as instructed, though, and force another language (eg: french) on my magento checkout, I can see that only the "pay now" button has been translated to french. The "Pay later" button kept its original language.
So the locale parameter doesn't  work on the pay later button.
Is there a way to force the translation of this button too?
